# Ubuntu 12.04.3 installation on a DOS netbook

Tags: installation, ubuntu-netbook

I am planning to buy an Asus netbook with the following configuration:

Asus 1015E-CY041D
Memory: 2 GB
HDD 320GB
Clock Speed: 64Bit
Processor: Celeron Dual Core 847
DOS

I have also created a bootable USB using Universal USB Installer for Ubuntu 12.04.3

Can I use this to install Ubuntu on the netbook without having windows installed on it??

Comment: If USB Boot is enabled in BIOS. YES

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can install Ubuntu to any computers but you might have some driver issues after installation which can be fixed. So I cannot say that it'll definitively work on this model without any problem. You need to install and see. If you face any problem just ask to the community. You can find all kind of drivers or answers for your questions.

According to Ubuntu, it works on some Asus models %100. Here is the link which you can see the certified models:

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Asus/

You don't need Windows. Just boot it with your usb and install.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an Asus X201E with a similar configuration. The difference being a Celeron Dual Core 1007U, came preintalled with DOS. Should be a breeze to install.  UEFI booting works fine if the bootable USB is created with Universal USB Installer(Windows) or Startup Disk Creator(Ubuntu). No adjustments in BIOS settings have to be made.